# Django query model and return true if user in ManyToMany-field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, orm

I have a model like this:

```
class FeedItem(models.Model)
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
source = models.ForeignKey(Source, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
read_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='read')
deleted_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='deleted')
```

I'm using rest framework to build an API. I would like to query the model above but not return the whole list of users in read_by and deleted_by but instead return True or False in those fields if the user that is Authenticated appears in those fields. Is there and way to do this in `FeedItem.objects.filter( ... )`. Below is my current API endpoint.

```
class Posts(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = FeedItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExampleModelSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter]
    filterset_fields = ['title']
    ordering_fields = ['title']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this using [`Conditional Expression: Case`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case):

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, BooleanField

class Posts(generics.ListAPIView):
    ...
    
    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(**kwargs)
        return queryset.annotate(
            read_by_you=Case(
                When(
                    read_by=self.request.user,
                    then=Value(True)
                ),
                default=Value(False),
                output_field=BooleanField()
            )
        )
```

Comment: Thank you! Just had to change my serializer to not be a modelSerializer and I got it working.

Comment: Oops, I did not notice it was ListAPIView, not list view.